# Data type mismatch in criteria expression using access 2013

Tags: vb.net, oledb

Every Time i click the save button it says that data type mismatch in criteria expression what does it mean?

```
Try
    command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    With command
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO [tbl_monitoring] ([DelNum], [PlateNum], [Driver], [Helper], [DateDel], [Customer], [Product]) VALUES ([@DelNum], [@PlateNum], [@Driver], [@Helper], [@DateDel], [@Customer], [@Product])"
```

Comment: Every Time i click the save button it says that data type mismatch in criteria expression what does it mean? pls help.

Comment: Not enough code there to tell much - in fact the exception cant come from one of those lines. The error message tells you it has to do with the Data Types, but you dont show the param values.

Comment: Please [**check this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155538/how-do-you-trouble-shoot-a-data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression-error-in) I believe it is your issue and sounds like a duplicate...